# There is a leak in the Activity but which part of the code takes a reference to the Activity? is it detectable from Android-Profiler?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-profiler

In an Android application,

I have found that one of the activities has memory leak
Leak canary shows the leak and Android Profiler shows the leak too

As you can see in the figure, there are 2 instances of Warrior_TypeA_Activity which indicates there is a leak

Ok, there is a leak in the Activity but which part of the code takes a reference to the Activity?

How can I detect it from the Reference table of Android Prodiler?

[image]

Comment: LeakCanary can analyze the heap dump to give you hints about what is retaining your activity.

Comment: What about Android Profiler?